# PHP - Public function inside foreach loop (WordPress widget)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops, foreach

I'm very new to PHP, so this may be a simple (and stupid) question.

I'm coding a widget in WordPress, and I need to find the link for the avatar, for each user, shown after a search.

Right now I have this:

```
<?php
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

}?>
```

I need to parse the user ID, into this function:

```
public function get_avatar_url( $id, $args = null ) {
    $args = get_avatar_data( $id, $args );
    return $args['url'];
}
```

How can I put the public function inside the foreach-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a public function in a foreach loop, but you need to "open" or instantiate your object in the loop.

Depending on the class name, you can do something like this :

```
<?php
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        $object = new yourclassname($user->ID); // maybe you don't need $user->ID to create this object
        $args = array();
        $avatar_url = $object->get_avatar_url($user->ID, $args);
    }
?>
```

Some class only need to be instantiate once before the foreach loop, it will depends on what the class is doing.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi Benoti
As I said, I'm very new to PHP.

Does it make any difference if it's not a public function?

I'm not quite sure how the $object works :/ (sorry)

Comment: Yeah Grillo, you must try, read doc, read source code, that's how you can learn. We don't have enough elements to help you more with your given code. But For your primary question, yes it will make a difference if it's a static or a private function. But, in fact, it depends where the foreach loop stands. If the foreach loop is part of the class, function are accessible easily. If not, you need the function to be static or public and need to be access like I show you or like this yourclassname::get_avatar_url().